# Raspberry pi NTP working without conf file

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, systemd, ntp

On raspberry, I was looking at the NTP configuration file under `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`. All lines are commented (by default) but when I run the `timedatectl status` command, I get:

```
...
Network time on : yes
NTP synchronized : yes
...
```

How NTP works without configuration in conf file ? Where are NTP server links ?

Raspberry pi 3 ; Raspbian 9.13 (stretch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NTP management of systemd is called [systemd-timesyncd](http://transit.iut2.upmf-grenoble.fr/cgi-bin/man/man2html?systemd-timesyncd+8). On my Ubuntu system, the corresponding systemd service is */lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service*. Typically, when you don't have items activated in a configuration file, daemons use default values. Moreover, if you look at the comment in the configuration file, you will see that the commented items are actually default values:

> Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
> You can change settings by editing this file.
> Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.